# Como corregir este script del sql

Tags: sql-server, linq

relice este script en sql server para obtener la suma de de importes descritos aqui abajo, el inconveniente es que no se como realizarlo en linq

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(q1.Ejercicio, q2.Ejercicio) AS Ejercicio, 
    COALESCE(q1.TotalGastos, 0) AS TotalGastos, 
    COALESCE(q2.TotalReal, 0) AS TotalReal
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Ejercicio, 
        SUM(Imp01) + SUM(Imp02) + SUM(Imp03) + SUM(Imp04) + SUM(Imp05) + SUM(Imp06) + SUM(Imp07) + SUM(Imp08) + SUM(Imp09) + SUM(Imp10) + SUM(Imp11) + SUM(Imp12) AS TotalGastos
    FROM 
        DASH_GASTOS
    WHERE 
        Oper = 1
    GROUP BY 
        Ejercicio) AS q1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        Ejercicio, 
        SUM(Imp01) + SUM(Imp02) + SUM(Imp03) + SUM(Imp04) + SUM(Imp05) + SUM(Imp06) + SUM(Imp07) + SUM(Imp08) + SUM(Imp09) + SUM(Imp10) + SUM(Imp11) + SUM(Imp12) AS TotalReal
    FROM 
        DASH_GASTOS
    WHERE 
        Oper = 2
    GROUP BY 
        Ejercicio) AS q2
ON 
    q1.Ejercicio = q2.Ejercicio
```

Dando como resultado :

```
Ejercicio | TotalGastos | TotalReal
----------|-------------|----------
2021      | 0           |   1232.20
2022      | 0           |1515151.15
2023      |81141414.10  |515454544.1
```

Como puedo pasarlo a linq ya que no puedo cambiarlo a esa estructura

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Investigando un poco reformule mi consulta de sql de esta manera:

```
SELECT Ejercicio, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Oper = 1 THEN Imp01 + Imp02 + Imp03 + Imp04 + Imp05 + Imp06 + Imp07 + Imp08 + Imp09 + Imp10 + Imp11 + Imp12 END), 0) AS TotalGastos, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Oper = 2 THEN Imp01 + Imp02 + Imp03 + Imp04 + Imp05 + Imp06 + Imp07 + Imp08 + Imp09 + Imp10 + Imp11 + Imp12 END), 0) AS TotalGastosReal
FROM DASH_GASTOS
GROUP BY Ejercicio;
```

y al pasarla a linq quedo de esta manera:

```
var result = (from g in bd.DashGastos
                              group g by g.Ejercicio into grp
                              select new
                              {
                                  Ejercicio = grp.Key,
                                  TotalGastos = grp.Where(x => x.Oper == "1").Sum(x => x.Imp01 + x.Imp02 + x.Imp03 + x.Imp04 + x.Imp05 + x.Imp06 + x.Imp07 + x.Imp08 + x.Imp09 + x.Imp10 + x.Imp11 + x.Imp12) ?? 0,
                                  TotalGastosReal = grp.Where(x => x.Oper == "2").Sum(x => x.Imp01 + x.Imp02 + x.Imp03 + x.Imp04 + x.Imp05 + x.Imp06 + x.Imp07 + x.Imp08 + x.Imp09 + x.Imp10 + x.Imp11 + x.Imp12) ?? 0,
                              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Cuidado con esa opción porque si una columna tiene un valor nulo, toda la fila terminará con valor nulo y mostrará importes incorrectos.

Comment: Como podría corregirlo, y solventar ese error

Comment: Podría darte las posibles soluciones en SQL, pero no conozco la sintaxis de Linq. Básicamente tienes que cambiar nulos por ceros, o verificar que las columnas no acepten nulos.

Comment: los doble entiendo que los campos de suma son int o double, float etc. en c# no tiene null, tienen el formato no Numerico para eso y ni eso  en los intpara los where estan facil como meterle un and `&&` no es null

Comment: ¿Perdón?  es que no te entendí nada